# How to make the link 'index.php?x' display x section on a page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was trying to make a site with different parts which will be shown with a questionmark (like index.php?notes, index.php?options, etc.). Normally I see this often on search query pages or blogs (with an ?q="question").

On my index.php page i have set multiple sections that will be shown if the user presses a href link.

I know that this can be done with the anchor link in css (with #options), but since I am using php, I would like to try that.

This is my code at the moment:

```
<body>
  <p>
[<a href="?notes">Notes</a>]
[<a href="?categories">Categories</a>]
[<a href="?options">Options</a>]
 </p>

 <?php
if($display == 'categories') {
echo "<h4>Categories</h4>";
} else if ($display == "notes") {
    echo "<h4>Delete Notes</h4>";
} else {
    echo "<h4>Options</h4>";
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: What is `$display`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `?q=question` you can access it in PHP via `$_GET['q']`. In your case, since you don't have `q` set, but `?notes` you need to access it via `$_GET['notes']`. Try this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['categories'])) {
    echo "<h4>Categories</h4>";
} elseif (isset($_GET['notes'])) {
    echo "<h4>Delete Notes</h4>";
} else {
    echo "<h4>Options</h4>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use any keys, then you can use this code:

```
if(isset($_GET)){
    $page = key($_GET);
}
```

But this solution is not very good it can mess your code later. I suggest to use with key i.e. ?p=notes

Answer (score -1):

You could set a GET variable `p` and read that; e.g.

`<a href="?p=notes">notes</a>` and in PHP `$_GET['p']`